# I am getting this error "TypeError: userData.map is not a function" using fetchAPI and useState

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am getting an error trying to fetch data from API and display them in return. I am using useState and useEffect. Truly, I still don't understand it and I am trying to learn and achieve this.

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'

function About() {
    const [userData, setUserData] = useState(true)
    async function getData() 
        {
           let response = await fetch('https://api.github.com/users');
           let data = await response.json();
            setUserData(data)
            return data;
        }
        //call getData function
        // getData()
        // .then(data => console.log(data)
        // );//
    useEffect(() => {
        getData()
        .then(
           data => {
               setUserData(data) }
        )
    }, [])

    return (
        <div>
           {
             userData.map((item, index) => (
                 <div key={index}>
                     <span>{item.login}</span>
                 </div>
             ))
           }
                 
        </div>
    )
}
```

I will like learn if there is any material to point me to, I have searched but I saw setState for class-based component but I am using function-based component

Comment: I think userData is not an array but an object. Can you consol.log it?. In addition, set the initial state to an empty array, not true.

Comment: Wow thanks, I have changed it to array and now it displays. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I think there are two issues.

First, by setting the state to true, you cannot map it. In other words you are trying to do `true.map` which cannot be performed on a boolean. Set the state to empty array.

Second always check that the data you get is an array, otherwise you cannot use `.map`

Comment: I didn't check that it was auto-complete and I have changed it to const [userData, setUserData] = useState([])

Answer (score 0):

you just need to replace these code : const [userData, setUserData] = useState(true)

//if your response is in Array format then:
By this code : const [userData, setUserData] = useState([])

//if your response is in Object format then:
By this code : const [userData, setUserData] = useState({})

It worked for me